# old Designjet 430 with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, parallel-port, lpt

How do you install windows 10 drivers for an old designjet 430 hp plotter?

It has a parallels port (LPT port), no USB.

I haven't been able to find Windows 10 drivers for it.

Comment: I disagree, that question specifically asks about a deskjet, is completely different hardware from a plotter. I know you are defending stack's goals, but when people search "how do I get my designjet 430 to work", the LPT port question wont show up. Second, this question is not so much about the cable as it is about how/where to procure and install drivers that aren't available from HP's website. So no, this question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### STEP 1  -  Buy a USB to Parallel IEEE 1284 cable.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00IDU0T1Y/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00IDU0T1Y)

```
Sabrent USB to Parallel IEEE 1284 Printer Cable Adapter (CB-CN36)
```

[image]

#### STEP 2 - Connect cable to computer and plotter, turn on plotter.

Windows should automatically install the necessary drivers for the cable.

[image]

When windows is done installing the drivers for the cable, it should appear like so:

[image]

Under device manager, the cable should appear as USB Printing Supporting.

[image]

#### STEP 3 - Install driver for printer.

Next, it is necessary to install the driver for the plotter

Verify cable is properly installed:

```
Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers
```

It should list the cable as USB2.0-Print

[image]

Disable driver signing in windows. Not 100% sure this step is necessary:

Open command prompt as administrator (or else it won't work) and enter.

```
bcdedit.exe /set nointegritychecks on
```

[image]

Restart the computer.

Download the driver. It is called

```
hpdj430x64glen.exe
```

http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=47388879835287571395

Extract the driver by double clicking it.

Use the "Add a printer" button in the 'Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers' dialog window on the top left.

[image]

[image]

Chose install from disk:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### STEP 4 - If the printer doesn't work, use the other USB002 (instead of USB001 virtual port). This makes a difference.

If done in this order, you should be able to print through the newly added printer.